# Error when searching in SharePoint 2010

Tags: search

> The DataSourceID of 'TopNavigationMenuV4' must be the ID of a control of type IHierarchicalDataSource.  A control with ID 'topSiteMap' could not be found.

Could some one help me to fix the above error?
I am getting this error when I search for an item. I have checked the Crawl service and it is fine. 
I have checked the web.config for any errors or extra characters. But there is nothing wrong with the web.config. I have also checked the permissions. This is also fine.

Answer (score 0):

Corey Roth has blogged about this exact issue:

http://dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2007/12/05/the-datasourceid-of-topnavigationmenu-must-be-the-id-of-a-control-of-type-ihierarchicaldatasource-a-control-with-id-topsitemap-could-not-be-found.aspx

Comment: tried the above but it did not fix the problem. I dont see any problem for the root site. But I get this error only when I try accessing the site collection under the root.